# Adding Windows.Services.Store lib to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-store-apps

Currently I'm working on an **WPF** app that will be packaged as **UWP** app so I can publish it in **Windows Store**. I'm following this video in making this happened (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJkbYPyd08w)

Now, I want my application to implement **Subscription Base** service. So I found this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app

But it seems that I can't add UWP **Windows.Services.Store** Namespace library into my project. I try to seek in Nuget without success.

Where can I get this library? How to use it in WPF?

Thanks

Comment: Universal Windows Platform or UWP is a UI Framework that was built on and runs on the .NET Core. Windows Presentation Foundation is a UI Framework that was built for and runs on the .NET Framework. So your problem is that you're trying to reference and use a .NET Core DLL from within a .NET Framework package, which is impossible.

Comment: Did you find a solution? My app is refused by the Windows store because i use an external method to purchase the product...

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add the *Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts* NuGet package to your project. For details, see this [blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/calling-windows-10-apis-from-a-desktop-application-just-got-easier/).

Comment: If you are using .Net 5.0 or later, do not do this. Instead, you need to specify the version of the windows APIs you need to use in the target framework for you project. For more info, see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1130?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(NETSDK1130)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** WPF runs on .NET Framework, UWP on .NET Core. .NET Framework and .NET Core cannot directly share code with each other, for this you require .NET Standard class libraries.

I see that you're quite new to C#, so I'll try to keep it short and simple.

.NET is a lot more than people think it is, what most people mean by .NET is the .NET Framework. What it actually is, is the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) and the Common Intermediate Language (Historically MSIL now CIL), on top of which you have the .NET Standard, this is a base collection of classes that all .NET implementations must have and is the way of sharing code between different Frameworks.

Another layer up you get the Frameworks. .NET Framework being the most popular but also the oldest, it features ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF and more.
The .NET Core is the Framework form Microsoft featuring Cross-Platform support, so your programs can run on Windows, Linux and OS X, UWP runs on the .NET Core.

[Here](https://d585tldpucybw.cloudfront.net/sfimages/default-source/blogs/dotnet-today.png?sfvrsn=b91db322_2) is a great diagram visualizing this

**Note:** In the upcoming release of the .NET Core 3.0, you will be able to create WPF applications running on windows (WPF will not be supported on Linux or OS X)

Comment: I'm testing an approach from here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#kA0STOUl6Z9fAz0F.97 ... and also from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#desktop ... lets hope it will works